# How to stop stream in "Red5 Pro HTML"?

Tags: javascript, web, stream, red5pro

Dear friends i cant find in documentation of "Red5 Pro HTML" precise example how to stop stream for publisher, please if some one know write way give me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [SDK documentation](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/static/html5-streaming/RTCPublisher.html), both `RTCPublisher` and `RTMPPublisher` have a function named `unpublish`:

> **unpublish()** → {Promise}
>
> Request to stop a broadcast. The returned Promise will either resolve or reject on successful stop of broadcast.
>
> Returns: `Promise`

Try using that.

```
publisher.unpublish()
  .then(() => console.log('Stopped publisher stream!'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Failed to stop publisher stream!'))
```

Comment: @ДенисМогила I'm glad I could help! You can accept the answer by clicking on the [checkbox left of the answer](https://i.imgur.com/BvrkwLA.png).